# Binary code and Hamming distance

Tags: coding-theory, hamming-code, binary

I'm learning about CRC and Hamming distance and I have three questions.
Lets say we have binary code described by ($+$ refers to sum modulo $2$):

\begin{alignat*}{1}
a_1 &+ a_2 &+ a_3 &+ a_4 &+ a_5 &= 0\\
a_6 &+ a_7 &+ a_8 &+ a_9 &+ a_{10} &= 0\\
a_1 &+ a_6 &+ a_{11} &&&= 0\\
a_2 &+ a_7 &+ a_{12} &&&= 0\\
a_3 &+ a_8 &+ a_{13} &&&= 0\\
a_4 &+ a_9 &+ a_{14} &&&= 0\\
a_5 &+ a_{10} &+ a_{15} &&&= 0
\end{alignat*}
We received: $11011\ 01010\ 10111$

So if I would like to check minimal Hamming distance, then I should compare each codeword with others, right?

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1& & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & &1&1&1&1&1& & & & & \\
1& & & & &1& & & & &1& & & & \\
 &1& & & & &1& & & & &1& & & \\ 
 & &1& & & & &1& & & & &1& & \\
 & & &1& & & & &1& & & & &1& \\
 & & & &1& & & & &1& & & & &1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

I have done so, and minimal Hamming distance $ = 6$. Is there any faster method?

Second question: how many distortions causing undetectable errors? Is there any formula for that? 
And last one, how to compute redundancy using above information. I'm using formula:
 $ R = \dfrac{n-k}{n}$. In above example $n=15$, but I don't understand how to obtain $k$.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: The rule is one question per post. Your two questions are completely unrelated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum hamming distance of multiple binary words](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68683/minimum-hamming-distance-of-multiple-binary-words)

Answer (score 1):

In a linear code, the minimum distance is the same as the minimum weight of a non-zero codeword. It's a nice exercise to prove this, and reduces the computation time quadratically.

Computing the minimum distance of a code given the generator matrix (or the parity check matrix) is NP-hard, that is, given a generator matrix (or a parity check matrix) and an integer $w$, it is NP-complete to determine whether the minimum distance of the code generated by the matrix is at most $w$. The task could become easier if the code has some structure, but for arbitrary codes it is quite difficult.